# Speech Recognition in Windows 8.1 and Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, windows-8.1

I want to develop app for window store 8.1 and phone 8 using speech recognition.Can anyone here suggest me good tutorial for beginners.
Which one to use  microsoft speech sdk or bing recognition control??
Which is easy for beginners ??

Answer (score 3):

the following MSDN links should help you to get started:

- [Speech for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206958%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
- [The Bing Speech Recognition Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx)

I can't say which one is easier to use for a beginner, because I never work with the Bing one, but especially on Windows Phone the speech recognition mentioned in the first link works pretty good.